# Accessing public elements from other modules

Tags: acceleo

I'm new to Acceleo, but I understand that modules have both private and public elements which can be accessed by other modules (via extending / importing those modules).

In my case I have

```
[module generate('my_model_URI')/]
[import com::example::ecore /]
...
```

where I'm importing another module which uses the `ECore` namespace.

I want to access the Ecore module's public elements - what is the notation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
ecore::EAttribute
```

or in the general form:

```
Module::Element
```

accesses public elements of a module.